# Moving a div with insertAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good afternoon:

I have a little problem using insertAfter .

In each store product I have a button to add to cart . This button position it wanted after the price.

To do this I used the code:

```
<Script type="text/javascript" >
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  JQuery('.Woo-buttons').insertAfter('price');
 });
</Script>
```

The problem is that with this code me many ( overlapping ) buttons as I have products appear . That is, if I have 10 products on page for each product me 10 buttons appear .

Any solution " simple "?

Thank you!

[Ex. With Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO04W.jpg)
[Web Link](http://dronaliaserviciosaereos.es/tienda-de-drones/)

Comment: What is going on with your formatting?

Comment: Use code in proper way `jQuery('.Woo-buttons').insertAfter(jQuery('.price'));`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
JQuery('.Woo-buttons').insertAfter(JQuery('.price').last());
});
</script>`

Not work :/

Comment: Check whether your script is at the end of your `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `price` tag in each product. Just add `.last()` to yor expression.
It will looks like this:

`JQuery('.Woo-buttons').insertAfter(JQuery('price').last());`

Comment: Thanks but dont work with the code `<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
JQuery('.Woo-buttons').insertAfter(JQuery('.price').last());
});
</script> `